# Extracting tuples into rows in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have got a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
function_name    argument                              A        B

func1            (func1_arg1, func1_arg2)             value_a1  b
func2            (func2_arg1,)                        value_a2  b
func3            (func3_arg1, func3_arg2, func3_arg3) value_a3  b
```

and I want it to look like so:

```
function_name   argument    A          B

func1           func1_arg1  value_a1   b
func1           func1_arg2  value_a1   b
func2           func2_arg1  value_a2   b
func3           func3_arg1  value_a3   b
func3           func3_arg2  value_a3   b
func3           func3_arg3  value_a3   b
```

What would be a clear way to achieve it?
In the interactive python mode, I tried doing the following:

```
import pandas as pd


D = {'function_name': ['func1', 'func2', 'func3'],
     'argument': [('func1_arg1', 'func1_arg2'), 
                  ('func2_arg1',), 
                  ('func3_arg1', 'func3_arg2', 'func3_arg3')],
     'A': ['value_a1', 'value_a2', 'value_a3'],
     'B': 'b'}
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(D)
multiplicity = data_frame.argument.apply(len)
new_index = data_frame.function_name.repeat(multiplicity).index
new_data_frame = data_frame.reindex(new_index)
```

Then I found out that in order to get the indexing that would allow me to work with tuples I have to reset the index by invoking the `reset_index(drop=True)` on the new_data_frame. In other words all this looks quite ugly and silly. Is there any clean and concise way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a dataframe `data_frame` then applying pd.Series after setting  the index as `function_name`, stacking and resetting the index will give you the resultant output

```
D = {'function_name': ['func1', 'func2', 'func3'],
 'argument': [('func1_arg1', 'func1_arg2'), 
              ('func2_arg1',), 
              ('func3_arg1', 'func3_arg2', 'func3_arg3')],
 'A': ['value_a1', 'value_a2', 'value_a3'],
 'B': 'b'}
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(D)

new_frame = data_frame.set_index(['function_name','A','B'])['argument'].apply(pd.Series).stack().to_frame('argument').reset_index().drop('level_3',1)
```

Output:

```
 function_name         A  B    argument
0         func1  value_a1  b  func1_arg1
1         func1  value_a1  b  func1_arg2
2         func2  value_a2  b  func2_arg1
3         func3  value_a3  b  func3_arg1
4         func3  value_a3  b  func3_arg2
5         func3  value_a3  b  func3_arg3
```

Comment: Wow perfect! But about that '0' above the original argument column? I'd like to save its name. I mean I know I can change it, but is it possible to do it 'on the fly', so to speak?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: If you found my answer helpful do accept it and upvote if possible.

Comment: yeah I'm about to do it, but I've just realised that my data_frame will contain more columns, and if I add them and then use your method, they get chopped off. I'm extremely sorry I didn't write it at once, would you please take this factor into account and update your answer one more time?

Comment: Can you update your question adding example columns in your data_frame?

Comment: Sure, give me a minute.

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope it helps

Comment: Yeah, immensely. Thank you!

Comment: I've done some refactoring of my code and now it looks like I will need more columns containing tuples. I've asked another question here and I would appreciate it if you would help me to solve this issue.

Comment: here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46022899/extracting-tuples-into-rows-from-numerous-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: I did answer it hope it helps .